# How to solve following equation?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

How to solve for $t$:
$\|X + Vt + At^2\| = r$

$\|x\|$ is vector norm.

I would prefer explanation of how to get to exact solutions, I know definitions, it's more of an algebraic difficulty for me.

Equation in other form:
$\sum (a_it^2 + v_it + x_i)^2 = r^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand the squares on the left, you will get a quartic in $t$.  These can be [solved algebraically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation), but it is a mess.  Maybe there is something special about your constants so it simplifies, or maybe you should just solve it numerically.

Comment: Could you specify? Newton's method will do? I mean I'm not a mathematician, I just recently learned what numerical analysis is in my university, so I'm not good very good in this kind of things.

Comment: @mrpyo: It will, **if** you manage to figure out good initial estimates for the roots.

Comment: Chapter 9 of Numerical Recipes http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html (obsolete versions are free) has a discussion of available methods with C code.  So will any numerical analysis text.